# Group by clause using max(date) mysql

Tags: mysql

Below is the structure of my table. I want the rows marked blue. My query isnt working even when using multiple group by.

```
SELECT * FROM drug_refills WHERE drug_inventory_id = 1 GROUP BY drug_entity_id, start_date
```

for the blue ticks the date is max followed by drug_entity_id (group by)

[image]

Comment: If ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled, a MySQL extension to the standard SQL use of GROUP BY permits the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns are not functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns. This causes MySQL to accept the preceding query. In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are nondeterministic, which is probably not what you want. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a correlated sub query to establish the last date

```
    drop table if exists t;
    create table t(drug_refill_id int auto_increment primary key,drug_inventory_id int,drug_entity_id int,start_date date);

    insert into t (drug_inventory_id,drug_entity_id, start_date) values
    (1,1,'2018-01-01'),(1,3,'2018-01-02'),(2,4,'2018-01-01'),(1,5,'2018-01-01'),(1,5,'2018-02-01');

    select * 
    from t 
    where start_date = (select max(start_date) from t t1 where t1.drug_entity_id = t.drug_entity_id) and
            drug_inventory_id = 1;

+----------------+-------------------+----------------+------------+
| drug_refill_id | drug_inventory_id | drug_entity_id | start_date |
+----------------+-------------------+----------------+------------+
|              1 |                 1 |              1 | 2018-01-01 |
|              2 |                 1 |              3 | 2018-01-02 |
|              5 |                 1 |              5 | 2018-02-01 |
+----------------+-------------------+----------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

BTW if you want answers to more closely resemble your data then include data as text in your question rather than images.